# multiplying Big O $\left(x^3+2x^2+O\left(x\right)\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

multiplying I reach to this result $x^3+3x^2+2x+O\left(x\right)+O\left(1\right)$

that is not right answer

Comment: I'm getting $x^3+3x^2+O(x)$: That is $(x^3+2x^2+O(x))(1+1/x+O(1/x^2))=x^3+2x^2+O(x)+x^2-2x+O(1)+O(x)+O(1)+O(1/x)=x^3+3x^2+O(x)$

Comment: sorry is not  minus 2x power 2

Comment: Note that $O(1)$ and $2x$ are both "encapsulated" in the $O(x)$...so they can be ignored

Comment: Is it at $0$ or at $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether
$x \to 0$
or
$x \to \infty$.

This is an odd question
since the first term
is of the form
usually associated with
$x \to 0$
and the second with
$x \to \infty$.

So,
until you tell us which holds,
there is no way
to answer this question.

Comment: $x \to \infty$ sorry I forgot put it